# Model property not being passed to Razor View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am currently working on a project to model a bikestore.  However, I am running into several issues:

1.) For some reason, Name from Order.Create is not being passed to Order.  Why is this?
2.)I would like the dropdownList in Order.Create to remove any Order not from the store in the SelectList via JQuery.  How would I go about this?

Code is below.  If you have any questions/file requests/criticisms, Feel free to ask.

Order.Create:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventory[i].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventory[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventory[i].Price)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Inventory[i].IsSelected)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Inventory[i].IsSelected, Model.Inventory[i].Name)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Inventory[i].Price)
                </div>
            }
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PaymentMethod)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentMethod)
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StoreId, "StoreId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownList("StoreId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            </div>
```

Inventory Model:

```
public class Inventory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
        public int? StoreId { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Decimal InventoryCost { get; set; }

        public Decimal RecSalePrice { get; set; }

        public Decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }

        public virtual BikeCategory Category { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
```

Store Model:

```
public class Store
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public int Zip { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Hours { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Inventory> StoreInventory { get; set; }

        public Store() 
        {
            Name = "";
            Employees=new List<Employee>();
            StoreInventory = new List<Inventory>();
        }
```

Order Model:

```
 public class Order
    {
        public Order()
        {
            OrderedItems = new List<Inventory>();
        }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; } //FROM CONTROLLER User.Identity.Name

        public virtual List<Inventory> OrderedItems { get; set; }
        //public virtual List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? PickupDate { get; set; }

         [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual Store StoreOrderedFrom { get; set; }
        public int? StoreId { get; set; }

        public Decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
```

OrderVM Model:

```
public class OrderVM


     {
            public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
            public int? StoreId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
            public List<InventoryVM> Inventory { get; set; }
        }
```

InventoryVM Model:

```
public class InventoryVM
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
        public int? StoreId { get; set; }
    }
```

OrderedItemModel:

OrderController:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
    {
        private BikeStoreContext db = new BikeStoreContext();

        // GET: Orders

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Orders.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Orders/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // GET: Orders/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var inventory = db.StoreInventory;
            OrderVM model = new OrderVM
            {
                Inventory = inventory.Select(i => new InventoryVM { Id = i.Id, Name = i.Model, Price=i.RecSalePrice}).ToList()

            };
            ViewBag.StoreId= new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "Name");

            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Orders/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PaymentMethod, Inventory")]OrderVM model)
        {
            var Order = new Order
            {

                CustomerName = model.Name,
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                PaymentMethod = model.PaymentMethod,
                TotalCost=0,
                PickupDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                StoreOrderedFrom=db.Stores.Find(model.StoreId),
                StoreId=model.StoreId


            };

            IEnumerable<int> selectedItems = model.Inventory.Where(i => i.IsSelected).Select(i => i.Id);
            foreach(var item in selectedItems)
            {
                var orderItem = new OrderedItem { OrderId = Order.OrderNumber, InventoryId = item };
                db.OrderedItems.Add(orderItem);
                Order.TotalCost = Order.TotalCost + model.Inventory.Find(i => i.Id == item).Price;
                db.StoreInventory.Remove(db.StoreInventory.Find(item));
            }
            db.Orders.Add(Order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            model.Inventory.RemoveAll(i => i.IsSelected);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.StoreId = new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "Name", model.StoreId);
            return View(model);

        }

        // GET: Orders/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // POST: Orders/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "OrderNumber,CustomerName,OrderDate,PickupDate,TotalCost,PaymentMethod")] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // GET: Orders/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // POST: Orders/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            db.Orders.Remove(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2) when you say you want to remove Order, do you mean you want to hide the Inventory divs above?

Comment: @JamieD77 I want there to be a dropdown list of stores.  Selecting a store  will cause the select list to change to show only the items in that store.

Comment: `OrderVM` is a view model. You never use the `[Bind]` attribute when using a view model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you dont have Name in your `[Bind(Include = "PaymentMethod, Inventory")]` so it's being excluded.